# Avoid duplicate data when AWS Glue job feeds Amazon Redshift database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

How can I prevent duplicate data transfer to an Amazon Redshift table using an AWS Glue job? I have a scenario where daily CSV files are added to an S3 bucket, and my Glue job, which transfers data from these CSV files to a Redshift table, repeats the transfer of all files each time it runs. Is there a way to avoid duplicating data in this process?

I tried modifying the glue script but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable job [bookmarks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html).

Alternatively, you can develop a personalized Python script responsible for duplicating all the files that have undergone processing within a designated directory named 'importedFiles.' This way, each time your task initiates a new execution, you will have a precise record of the files you've handled.

Comment: Thanks so much.it worked with bookmarks enable.

Answer (score 0):

Use spectrum to query the data from s3 without loading it into redshift, no need for a scheduled job. Or use the new preview [auto copy](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/11/amazon-redshift-supports-auto-copy-amazon-s3/) capability